# How to validate a domain name with regex Bash script?

Tags: bash, scripts, regex

I'm trying to validate any domain name but it seems doesn't work the match. Don't understand why the syntax looks fine and I also verified this regex on https://rubular.com/r/QmX59URV8D
It's working fine.

here's my code

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter a domain name: " domain

# Validate domain name
validate="(?=^.{5,254}$)(^(?:(?!\d+\.)[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{1,63}\.?)+(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,})$)"

# If user doesn't enter anything
if [ -e $domain ]; then
    echo "You must enter a domain"
fi

if [[ $domain =~ $validate ]]; then
    echo "Valide $domain name."
else
    echo "Not valid $domain name."
fi
```

Comment: bash's `=~` uses the *extended regular expression* feature set - you appear to be trying to validate it as a Ruby regular expression. See [Bash =~ regex and https://regex101.com/](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421460/bash-regex-and-https-regex101-com) and [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Comment: ... as well, `[ -e $domain ]` tests for *file existance* - if you want to test whether a variable is empty, you want `[ -z "$domain" ]` or `[[ -z $domain ]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you need to use a Bash-compatible regex, not a Ruby one, as mentioned in the comments.

Next to use the `=~` comparison operator you need to use double  brackets`[[` and `]]` not single brackets.

And as also mentioned in the comments use `-z` to check if the read in variable is empty.

Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter a domain name: " domain

# Validate domain name
validate="^([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}$"

# If user doesn't enter anything
if [[ -z "$domain" ]]; then
    echo "You must enter a domain"
fi

if [[ "$domain" =~ $validate ]]; then
    echo "Valid $domain name."
else
    echo "Not valid $domain name."
fi
```

Should get you started.

Comment: It's working but why would you need to use longer Regex check?  I make it shorter and it seems to work well validdomain="^([a-z0-9]{1,60}\.)+[a-z]{2,3}$"

Comment: @BruceQ. Because domain names can have uppercase letters and hyphens in them, but a component of a domain name cannot start or end with a hyphen. Yours won't allow a hyphen or uppercase letter at all. Also, these days, some top level domains are longer than three characters (e.g., `.info`) and yours doesn't allow for that either.